# Pandas randomly split/select dataset based on sessionid

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to randomly split my dataset to the train and test subsets that looks like :

```
        x      in            session_id    page_id
0     0.0     1.0     trn-04a23351-283d       paul
1    -1.0     2.0     trn-04a23351-283d       paul2
2    -1.0     3.0     trn-04a23351-283d       paul3
3    -1.0     4.0     trn-04a23351-283d       paul4
4    -1.0     1.0      blz-412313we-333       paul
5    -1.0     2.0      blz-412313we-333       paul
27    0.0     1.0               adasdfs      sarah
28   -1.0     2.0               adasdfs      sarah
29    0.0     3.0               adasdfs      sarah
```

based on the session_id column. I want randomly split sessions into two datasets. And after that take all interactions for these sessions. The naive way to do it is :

```
df['is_train'] = df.groupby('session_id').session_id.transform(lambda x: np.random.ranf() > ratio)
```

But using python lambda downgrades performance too much.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GroupShuffleSplit.html) helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem with your method is that you use `np.random.ranf` and do the comparison as many time as you have groups and it is not really efficient. You can consider [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) the session_id column with a series created from [`unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) value of this column and `np.random.ranf` of the size of unique values in session_id with [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nunique.html) and do the comparison with ratio on the whole series at once:

```
df['is_train'] = df.session_id.map(pd.Series( np.random.ranf(df.session_id.nunique()),
                                              index=df.session_id.unique())) > ratio
```

It should be faster.

Comment: 1s vs 0.014 s for the same dataset. It is the best solution for this case